# How to refactor class in order to be testable without reflection

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have a class similar to this:

```
public class QueueingCommandRunner {
    private Status status;
    private Map<Class<CommandHandler>, CommandHandler> queuedCommands;
    private RunnerClass runnerClass;
    private ExternalCommandRunnerRegistry externalCommandRunnerRegistry;
    private ExternalCommandRunner externalCommandRunner;

    public QueueingCommandRunner(ExternalCommandRunnerRegistry externalCommandRunnerRegistry,
            RunnerClass runnerClass) {

        this.externalCommandRunnerRegistry = externalCommandRunnerRegistry;
        this.runnerClass = runnerClass;
        this.queuedCommands = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.status = Status.DOWN;
    }

    public void init() {
        doSomeStuff();
        externalCommandRunner = externalCommandRunnerRegistry.get(runnerClass);
        externalCommandRunner.runListeningCommand(ListenableStatusCommand.class,
                new ListenableStatusHandler(this::changeStatus));
    }

    public <T extends CommandHandler> void runCommand(Class<T> command, T commandHandler) {
        if (status == UP) {
            externalCommandRunner.run(command, commandHandler);
        } else {
            queuedCommands.put(command, commandHandler);
        }
    }

    private void changeStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
        if (status == UP) {
            Iterator<Entry<Class<CommandHandler>, CommandHandler>> commandsIterator =
                queuedCommands.iterator();
            while (commandsIterator.hasNext()) {
                <Entry<Class<CommandHandler>, CommandHandler>> queuedCommand = commandsIterator.next();
                externalCommandRunner.run(queuedCommand.getKey(), queuedCommand.getValue());
                commandsIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I omit stuff like synchronization. My question is, how to test queuing which is inside without using things like invocation of private methods via reflection? In particular I would like to know how to test `changeStatus` method since it is not directly run from any public method in this class. Is this class bad by design (from unit testing point of view)?

I am using JMockit for testing...

Comment: When Unittesting you verify the **desired public observable behavior** which is *return values* and *communication with dependencies* in relation to the provided input. Anything what happens inside your code under test is *implementation detail* and not tested (directly). This gives you the opportunity to change those *implementation details* to some more efficient or otherwise more desireable approach without changing the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comment - you test

> desired public observable behavior

So, if you want to test private methods you need to make them public. I suggest to make it as interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    changeStatus(Status status);
}
```

Then inject implementation to your class:

```
public final class A {

    private final SomeInterface someInterface;

    public A(SomeInterface someInterface) {
        this.someInterface = someInterface;
    }
}
```

Then you can easily test `SomeInterface` implementation and mock if you need it in your class `A`.

So, I cannot give you the whole refactoring process for your particular case. But you can follow this guideline and you can encapsulate all private methods with interfaces that are tested easily. As I can see, you are using internal details of your class in private methods - these details should be encapsulated in interface implementation constructor (via another interfaces) and you will end up with small nice cohesive testable classes. Look through [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) as it seems suitable for your case and try to follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) which will also lead to testable code.

I see several problems with your design:

- `init()` method. Which leads to temporal coupling as your class is not ready to use after construction;
- your `runCommand` method is doing two things based on status. It's either run command or put it to map (which is hidden side-effect);
- your `changeStatus` is also running comands.

You need to decouple those thins (running command, holding them and tracing status). Maybe encapsulate status of the command inside command itself. So the command will know how to work in its own way.